# Spring Oauth Token storing mechanism

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement Spring OAuth. I'm new to it and I'm trying to understand how it works.

My Questions:

1. OAuth generates token after authentication and this token must be used for every request the user makes. We need to append this access_token to each REST API call for accessing the resources. Did I sound correct?
2. Do we need to store this token on client side (using cookies)? or is there anyway so that we do not need to store this token at client side and can be handled on the server side?
3. If we have to store the token on client side what's the best way to do it? I have gone through this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/best-place-to-store-authentication-tokens-client-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If endpoint on your server is protected by oauth, then yes, you have to pass token with each request - probably in "Authorization: Bearer {token}" header. In spring its solved by using different restTemplate - `OAuth2RestTemplate` which automatically fetch it and add to request.
2. You just store just JSESSIONID in a cookie. Then spring read session from store ( disc where tomcat is installed / redis if you use spring session project/ etc )
3. Access token should be relatively short living. There should also be revoke endpoint available so you can invalidate specific token when there are reasons to believe it was compromised.

3.a) there is another issue with storing some data on client side. Its about storing clientId, clientSecret on mobile native apps. Android apps code can be reverse engineered quite easily, so anyone can then try to use your oauth app to get token. In those situations its recomennded to use different grant type "password" - check https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified#other-app-types

Comment: thank you for you answer. Can you please give me more details on JSESSIONID how to implement it? Provide me any links.

Comment: its a default cookie name used by spring to handle session. Try to store anything in a session within your spring controller. You should see this cookie in firebug then.